# iOS app submission issue (not signed using an Apple submission certificate)

Tags: ios, xcode

[image: I am facing these issues. I have searched many threads but no success. Please help me soon. Thanks in advance.]

As we can see errors in given image I have already recreated provisional profiles and also checked development target set to ios 4.3. Why do I encounter this error?

Comment: wrong certificate is used. double check.

Comment: Certificate is distribution. and provisional profile is for App store.

Comment: @Deniel , I think this is temporary issue from apple side, try Upload after some  time, check the bundle name again

Comment: @Deepesh yes every post showing same answer to wait for some time. But I am trying since for last 5 hours no success at all :(

Comment: check space in bundle name

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the Distribution Certificate, NOT the Developer Certificate. Then you need to have your provisioning profile added to the Distribution Certificate.

Comment: Surprised !! there was security framework missing and after adding its successfully uploaded

Comment: @SaygınKarahan When this error has occured I just updated Flurry SDK and with new sdk we need to add security.framework its available in ios bundle. and you can easily add it via build settings

Answer (score -1):

I just managed to solve this error formatting the macbook and generating new certificates.